# Retrofit2 Android: retrieve nested data (current error: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to retrieve some character data from the [Marvel API](https://developer.marvel.com/) which looks like this:

```
{
"code": 200,
"status": "Ok",
"copyright": "© 2019 MARVEL",
"attributionText": "Data provided by Marvel. © 2019 MARVEL",
"attributionHTML": "<a href=\"http://marvel.com\">Data provided by Marvel. © 2019 MARVEL</a>",
"etag": "cc6c6c3e7f5e336ecf899ab5652d55e6a3a51b09",
"data": 

{
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 20,
    "total": 1493,
    "count": 20,
    "results": 

[
        {
        "id": 1011334,
        "name": "3-D Man",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2014-04-29T14:18:17-0400",
        "thumbnail": {
        "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784",
        "extension": "jpg"
        },
        "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334",
        "comics": {},
        "series": {},
        "stories": {},
        "events": {},
        "urls": []
        },
```

But I obviously only want to show the results (data -> results -> array of characters), I was watching this tutorial where someone was able to get some data from a simple API where it was just an array (not nested). How could I make this work? Currently I got this code inside my activity:

```
textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textView_result);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        MarvelAPI marvelAPI = retrofit.create(MarvelAPI.class);

        Call<List<Character>> call = marvelAPI.getCharacters();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Character>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Character>> call, Response<List<Character>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                List<Character> characters = response.body();

                for (Character character : characters){
                    String content = "";
                    content += "ID: " + character.getId() + "\n";
                    content += "Name: " + character.getName() + "\n";
                    content += "Description: " + character.getDescription() + "\n";
                    content += "Modified: " + character.getModified() + "\n";
                    content += "Thumbnail: " + character.getThumbnail() + "\n";
                    textViewResult.append(content);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Character>> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

MarvelAPI interface which is being used in the activity:

```
public interface MarvelAPI {

    @GET("characters")
    Call<List<Character>> getCharacters();

}
```

This obviously doesn't work because it gives me an "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $" error. I also tried to make 2 new classes: **CharacterData** which has a list of results and also **CharactersResults** which has a list of Characters, but this doesn't work either (even after trying to change the call.enqueue and the MarvelAPI interface).. Or I just don't really know how to change my call.enqueue to let it take the right data with those 3 classes. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

(PS: I do know that putting all the results into a textview is messy but it's just first version to make the API retrieve the correct data, I do plan on putting it into a grid or something else)

Comment: refer this--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754771/retrofit-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this is actually using the models you mention. Essentially, make the java objects mimic the json structure. In this case you can do something like:

```
class CharacterData {
  @SerializedName("results")
  List<Character> characters;
  // ...
}

class CharactersResults {
  @SerializedName("data")
  CharacterData data;
  // ...
}
```

Like you said, now you need to change the retrofit calls. The interface for the proxy must now return `CharactersResults`:

```
public interface MarvelAPI {
  @GET("characters")
  Call<CharactersResults> getCharacters();
}
```

which in turn changes the callback parameters too:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<CharactersResults>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<CharactersResults> call, Response<CharactersResults> response) {
      // ...

      List<Character> characters = response.body().data.characters;

      // ...
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<CharactersResults> call, Throwable t) {
      // ...
   }
});
```

*PS: For brevity, I've ignored creating getters and setters*